# IPC/WCF pass List of <T>

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, wcf, ipc

i think this question has been asked lot's of time but i can't seem to get it to work even thought i read the articles from MSFT and some topics here on StackOverflow.

I'am really new to IPC/WCF but i start using it in my WPF applications because it's that simple. Now i have a situation in can't seem to get to work.

The issue is simple i want to pass a `List of <T>` to the server (which is also a WPF application). I can see it is send using Fiddler but upon serialisation nothing happens. This is because it's converted to an array to my understanding. So i adjusted it to an array but still no values.

To explain more let me add some code:

Shared(copy & pasted) **DataContract** between Client and Server:

```
<DataContract>
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)>
<KnownType(GetType(List(Of Integer)))>
Public Class UnauthorizedFolder
    <DataMember>
    Public Property RootFolderId As Integer

    <DataMember>
    Public Property ChildIds As New List(Of Integer)

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{RootFolderId} = [{String.Join(",", ChildIds)}]"
    End Function
End Class
```

Shared(copy & pasted) **Contract** between Client and Server

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface MyRemoteControls
    <OperationContract()> Sub UserAccessGranted(UserName As String, lstUnauthorisedFolders As List(Of UnauthorizedFolder))
    <OperationContract()> Sub UserAccessRevoked()
End Interface
```

Setup serverside:

```
_ServiceHost = New ServiceHost(GetType(RemoteControl), New Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyService"))
_ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(MyRemoteControls), New BasicHttpBinding(), "MyService")
_ServiceHost.Open()
```

And then the Server Remote Class:

```
Class RemoteControl
    Implements MyRemoteControls

    Dim strCurrentUserName As String

    Public Sub UserAccesGranted(UserName As String, lstUnauthorisedFolders As List(Of UnauthorizedFolder)) Implements MyRemoteControls.UserAccessGranted

        strCurrentUserName = UserName

        If lstUnauthorisedFolders Is Nothing OrElse lstUnauthorisedFolders.Count <= 0 Then
            Debug.Print($"{Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")} - UserAccesGranted: [{strCurrentUserName}] - All Folders{vbCrLf}")
        Else
            Debug.Print($"{Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")} - UserAccesGranted: [{strCurrentUserName}] {lstUnauthorisedFolders .Count}{vbCrLf}")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub UserAccesRevoked() Implements MyRemoteControls.UserAccessRevoked

        Debug.Print($"{Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")} - UserAccesRevoked: [{strCurrentUserName}]{vbCrLf}")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now from the client i can see that the XML is send to the server

```
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <UserAccessGranted
            xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <UserName>User 1(1)</UserName>
            <lstUnauthorisedFolders
                xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp"
                xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:UnauthorizedFolder>
                    <a:ChildIds
                        xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                        <b:int>1</b:int>
                        <b:int>2</b:int>
                        <b:int>4</b:int>
                        <b:int>5</b:int>
                        <b:int>8</b:int>
                    </a:ChildIds>
                    <a:RootFolderId>3</a:RootFolderId>
                </a:UnauthorizedFolder>
            </lstUnauthorisedFolders>
        </UserAccessGranted>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

So the client sends everything out the right way (Using `ChannelFactory`) but it seems upon serialisation at the server that `lstUnauthorisedFolders` isn't serialised.

I saw some answers describing i had to adjust the type in ServiceReference from `Array` to `Generic.List` to solve this issue but at the server application which is in WPF not ASP.NET i don't have such a setting?

A workaround I've tested and works is to use `Newtonsoft.JSON` to pass the `List of <T>` as string and then at the serverside serialise it back to `List of <T>` but i find this a ugly workaround since `List of <T>` is also supported in XML.

Hopefully someone could point me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: It is not an integer : <KnownType(GetType(List(Of Integer)))>  Should b <KnownType(GetType(List(Of  UnauthorizedFolder)))>

Comment: Ah keenly spotted, adjusted but unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: You controller has to start parsing the XML response at the same node your classes start.  The XML has an Envelope, Body, and UserAccessGranted.  Your root class is lstUnauthorisedFolders.  So where are you telling the controller to start at lstUnauthorisedFolders?

Comment: That's a good point. At the moment i asumed that the controller would handle this since i declared the types. Not sure how to change this, how would you set this up then?

Comment: The simplest way is to add classes for Envelope, Body, and UserAccessGranted

Comment: Could you share an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication184
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
            Envelope envelope = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(xReader);
        }
 
    }
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        public Body Body { get; set; }
    }
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace =  "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public UserAccessGranted UserAccessGranted { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserAccessGranted
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public lstUnauthorisedFolders lstUnauthorisedFolders { get; set; }
    }
    public class lstUnauthorisedFolders
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp")]
        public UnauthorizedFolder UnauthorizedFolder { get; set; }
    }
    public class UnauthorizedFolder
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp")]
        public ChildIds ChildIds { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp")]
        public int RootFolderId { get; set; }
    }
    public class ChildIds
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "int", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")]
        public List<int> numbers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this example! Since i'm still new if i just create these classes then the WCF serializer knows what to do?

Comment: See.  Response can be JSON, XML, and other types. :   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I tried your example and this indeed work. But although you send met the extra links i can't to seems to figure out how this would work in Winform/WPF? The links you'd send are meant for ASP.NET.

Comment: As long as you have to same "using statements" at top of module it should work.  You may need to add references to Net library.